# VBA Copy/Paste Into Another Workbook and Offset

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and paste a variable range from "Sheet 1" into "Sheet 2" and offset the cell that I'm pasting into Sheet 2 by one row. I'm doing this so I can add more data into Sheet 2 without overwriting data already pasted.

```
I created the desired copying ranges for sheet 1:


    Dim rw As Range
    Set rw = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range(Range("A4"), Range("A4").End(xlDown))
    

    Dim clm As Range
    Set clm = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range(Range("A4"), Range("A4").End(xlToRight))

Now I want to paste the range into Column A from Sheet 2 but under the last row used.

I got the following code to work to paste into cell A3 of Sheet 2:
Sheets("Sheet 1").Range(rw, clm).Copy Sheets("Sheet 2").Range("A3")

But I don't know how to offset by 1 row under every time.

Any help would be appreciated!
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Data From Table

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range("A4")
        Set srg = sws.Range(.End(xlDown), .End(xlToRight))
    End With
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    srg.Copy dfCell

End Sub
```